# dotnet core azure web app - okta application gateway

Tags: .net-core, azure-application-gateway

I have created dotnet core web application integrated with okta for identity. The application is hosted on azure web app which is behind azure application gateway.

The okta integration does not work because application is sending redirect_url which *.azurewebsites.net/authorization/callback instead of /authorization/callback.

i have added X-Forward-For code in `Configure` in startup.cs but no luck

```
app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
{
    ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedFor | ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
});

app.Use((context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Forwarded-Proto", out StringValues proto))
    {
        context.Request.Scheme = proto;
    }
    return next();
});
```

Do i need to any setup to allow custom domain name headers to be forwarded to application in application gateway?

Please advise?

Comment: Do you have a custom domain set in your backend azure web app?

Comment: Yes I do have it

Comment: What's hostname in web app service? Have you checked the box `pick host name from backend address` in the HTTP settings? For a custom domain whose existing custom DNS name is mapped to the app service, you don't have to enable this setting. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/configuration-overview#pick-host-name-from-back-end-address

Comment: Perhaps, you can follow [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-gateway/rewrite-http-headers#modify-a-redirection-url) to rewrite HTTP header for modifying a redirection URL. Currently, The HTTP header rewrite support is only available for sku V2. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Hi Is this issue resolved on your side?